# Getting domain installs for my Google Docs Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

We have a Google-docs Add-on (built on Google Apps Script) for which we enabled the Google Apps Marketplace SDK - so that Google Apps Administrators could install our add-on at the domain level.

We have noticed a few domains have now installed our add-on - but I can't seem to find a way to get information on which domains have installed us. Is it even possible?

I have tried the Marketplace license API https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/ but it fails with a 403 error - *Not authorized to access the application ID*.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Not authorized to access the application ID"
 }
}
```

I even tried by creating a **service account** and accessed the API using the service account but got the same error.

Any input would be awesome.

Here's my Java (Groovy technically) code so far (the response is the json I've pasted above):

```
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequestFactory
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory
import org.springframework.security.access.annotation.Secured

class DataController {

    /**
     * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
     * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
     */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "My app name";

    private static final String APPLICATION_ID = "12 digit project number";

    /** E-mail address of the service account. */
    private static final String SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "12digitproejectnumber-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com";

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();




    def getLicensedInfo() {

        try {
            try {
                httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();



                GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
                        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                        .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
                        .setServiceAccountScopes(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appsmarketplace.license"))
                        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("a/valid/path/to/key.p12"))
                        .build();


                credential.refreshToken();
                String token = credential.getAccessToken();

                HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);


                GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/appsmarket/v2/licenseNotification/"+APPLICATION_ID);

                HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);

                com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse response = request.execute();

                log.debug(response.parseAsString());


                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When making the request to the GAM License API you need to use the same Google Developers Console project that you used for your listing. In the case of an add-on, this is the console project associated with the script.

Comment: Thanks Eric. I've triple checked the project details I am using but still seem to be getting it wrong somewhere. Let me know if the following seem right:

* The application Id is the 12 digit project number of the console project associate with the script

* The service account Id needs to be a service account email associated with that same console project. I created a service account with Domain wide Delegation enabled. It has the format : 12digitprojectnumber-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com

* Also using the private key file for this service account

Comment: You don't need to use a service account to access this API. Trying using a regular OAuth2 user flow.

Comment: Hi Eric, thats the first thing I had tried via the "Try it" link on the LicenseNotification.list reference page. I got the 403 forbidden error. Screenshot:
https://www.evernote.com/l/AAJuA7KEmyNGmLCbwuVdbpoWV4iUU_DOyV0
I googled the issue and SO and there was multiple recommendations to use a service account - didn't work either.

Comment: The "Try it" link, aka APIs Explorer, won't work since it uses a different Google Developer Console project than your app is using.

Comment: of course it does :). I'll give a try with a regular OAuth flow using my account and report on the results. Thanks again.

Comment: Eric, That worked. Thanks so much. However, the data seems intentionally off so wanted to check with you. 

While the Marketplace SDK dashboard shows approx 80,000 seat installs, the API response shows seatCounts for the individual customer domains as "-1".  (I'm ignoring the results for individual end user installs)

Is this expected and is there a way to get seat install numbers per customer?

Example json result: http://pastebin.com/876V7YGD

Comment: No, as per the documentation the seatCount field is deprecated: https://developers.google.com/apps-marketplace/v2/reference/customerLicense#resource-representations

Comment: How is this information not accessible in GCP Console?